# How does linux detect the EOF of a text file?

Tags: c, linux

I was wondering how Linux detects the end of a text file. 
Do all text files end in a NULL byte, and Linux takes advantage of this?

Comment: The filesystem knows how big the file is and raises eof when the current index into the file is at the end and there's a request to read more.

Comment: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/ is good reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern operating systems, such as Linux, do not use the file contents to detect the end of the file, they store the file length in the file system and keep track of the file position to determine if more contents are available to read.

In fact, text files are not supposed to contain null bytes at all. They usually end with an end-of-line marker (`\n` on Linux and OS/X, `CR`/`LF` on legacy systems). One notable exception to this rule is the empty file.

When reading from a device such as the terminal window, the OS relies on the device driver to provide information about the end of the file, which in the case of the terminal can be signalled by the user by entering a system-specific key combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on Unix systems and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on Microsoft operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

From program point of view, `EOF` can detect using below API

1. `read()` return 0.
2. `getchar()` returns -1.

Comment: `getchar()` returns `EOF` (which commonly is defined as `-1` but the Standard allows other values).